# Is There a function which converts an audio file into array of hz?

Tags: python, signal-processing, librosa

I'm working on a project and try to compare audio file with another one.
I want to know the hz height of each signal in the audio and than check if it is accurate note or not.

For this I have tried librosa library but with it you need to crate mel spectogram and than work on the spec in order to find notes...
is there a simpler way?I prefer without CNN
Thanks
*maybe it's not so complicated to convert the spectogram as I thought...waiting to your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: simpler than mel spectrogram? maybe just FFT?